# My simulated coax cut off frequency is way far off the calculated value

Tags: rf, high-frequency, coax, cutoff-frequency

I used the lumped model to model a coax cable as a low pass filter in MATLAB. I also included ESR which is supposed to resemble the dielectric losses.

I derived my transfer function from the circuit below. I used voltage division to get my transfer function.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX3TSJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My MATLAB code has the transfer function "h" I derived:

```
    Fs = 0.002;
    s = 10: 1/Fs: 2*pi*1E9;
    d = 1E-3;
    D = 3E-3;
    er_d = 1/(0.66)^2;
    mu1 = 1;
    mu2 = 1;
    row1 = 0.234; 
    row2 = 0.234;
    eo = 8.85*1E-12;
    mu_o = 4*pi*1E-7;
    ed = er_d*eo;
 
R1 = sqrt(s.*mu1*mu_o/(2*1/row1));
R2 = sqrt(s.*mu2*mu_o/(2*1/row2));
Rs = R1+R2;
%lumped model
L = mu_o/(2*pi) * log(D/d);
C = (2*pi*ed)/log(D/d);
R = Rs/pi .* (1/D + 1/d);
ESR = (1/(10E18)) ./ (ed * s.^2 * C);
%ESR = 0;
h = (1./(C.*s.*1i) + ESR) ./( 1./(C.*s.*1i) + ESR + R + L.*1i.*s);

figure(1)
plot(s, 20*log(abs(h)));
set(gca, 'Xscale', 'log')
ylim([-8 0])
title('Coax cable modulation')
xlabel('Frequency in Rad/s');
ylabel('Gain in dB per meter');

grid

fc = 3E8/(pi*(D+d)/2 * sqrt(1*er_d))
```

My -3dB frequency from the resulting figure is in the MHz when it is supposed to be in the GHz. Why is that? I would truly appreciate some help. Thnx :D

[image]

Comment: What is the equivalent length in metres of your lumped model?

Comment: this model is supposed to resemble 1 meter only; my capacitance, resistance, and inductance are all per meter.

Comment: And how many wavelengths is 1 metre?

Comment: @BrianDrummond lambda = c/f, it depends on the frequency of the signal going through the cable? In this case, I am doing a frequency sweep.

Comment: Try again : how many wavelengths is 1 metre? Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model : "The lumped-element model is valid whenever L_{c}\<< lambda , where  L_{c} denotes the circuit's characteristic length, and lambda  denotes the circuit's operating wavelength"

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you, but I really don't know what you mean. I don't know if this answers your question, but I guess with the high frequencies I have, I can't use this lumped model to model the coax cable. Is that it?

Comment: OK you still haven't answered a simple question so I'll guess : you mention "the GHz range". Taking that to mean 1 GHz, 30cm wavelength, your metre is 3.3 wavelengths. That is squarely in the region where the lumped model won't work. You CAN replicate that circut scaled to << 30 cm (say, < 0.1 wavelength or 3 cm)  with 33 segments each providing 1/33 of the L, C, series R, and parallel conductance; connected to the correct source and load impedances. 100 segments (0.03 wavelengths) may be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This model unfortunately does not work. You have taken a inductance per meter, and assumed it means that 1 meter gives you that inductance as a lumped L. What you should do instead is break up a meter (or any other length) of coax into say 100 to 1000 pieces, calculate the Rl/Rc lump elements per segment (like the one you drew), and cascade them all. The smaller the segment the better your approximation.

You'll need to create a Matlab function to calculate the voltage divider, and then call it over and over again until you have all segments covered. You will see that the resulting impedance and transfer function are different from the one-lump model you have.

Here is an example of a cascade. It's taken from wikipedia on the topic of filters, but this is the idea. You need to add your R losses, and work from one end to the other, one segment at a time. Add a matched load Zload = Z0 to start with on the right hand side.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Say I want to divide my 1 meter to 1000 segments. Then, I need divide my R', L', and C' by 0.001 for each segment. Wouldn't these parameters be the same for all other segments? If so, all I need to do to get the overall transfer function is raise the transfer function of one segment to power 1000, correct?

Comment: to go from circuit to transfer function you have to also consider input/output impedance, which depends on how many segments come before and after respectively. This can get hairy. It's best to calculate the total circuit as a cascade of Z-circuits. A practical approach is to think of it as Z(f) -or Z(w)- and perform Z calculations numerically for each f (using Matlab's dot-mult and dot-divide), and work your way through the cascade. Each step is the same math, just different Z(f0) input.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about Z-Circuits online, but I think I understand. Basically, find the Thevenin equivalence of the previous segment to take into account in the current segment, and also consider the input impedance of the following segment, right? Also, will each segment be evaluated at different frequency span?

Comment: @maramalnahhas I edited my answer, I think you have it right

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for adding my 2 cents worth, without having the required professional background and without knowing all the maths and physics by heart...

A while ago, I've read a neat explanation of the lumped element model of a transmission line in layman terms - I'd attribute it to Microwaves101.com, but cannot find the precise meme on that site right now. And the meme goes like this, if my memory serves: the lumped element model of a transmission line scales with wavelength, and thus, frequency. Fractal style, I'd say. While the schematic looks like a multiple-stage low-pass filter, in reality the imagined L and C elements in the model are A) very small and B) proportional to wavelength. Thus, the nominal impedance ends up being independent of frequency - and, as there is hardly any loss, and "conservation of energy" applies, the coax does not behave like a low-pass filter. Not second-order, not even first order, definitely not like an infinite bank/cascade of the primal L/C combination. Yes there is some attenuation (loss of energy) that grows slowly with frequency, but that's down to various parasitic effects: neither the conductors nor the dielectric have ideal properties of the material, mechanical tolerances during manufacturing
also cause some signal loss... (picture it like a sequence of miniature local impedance mismatch reflections, spread along the length of coax cable).
I mean to say that your model with just a single C and just a single L
is probably over-simplified :-)

EDIT: three particular links to Microwaves101 - still not the meme I'm looking for, but might help shed some light:

[Transmission line model](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/transmission-line-model) - look for a heading called "Transmission line characteristic impedance"

[Characteristic impedance](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/characteristic-impedance)

[Coax equations](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/coax)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I think this ties back to one of the comments above about the lumped model. This is not as simple as I thought...

Comment: I still cannot find that darn reference, but let me try and put it this way: what if the rule really is, that the right "lumping scale is", that the "atomic LC circuits" are at resonance for a particular frequency that you test at? At resonance = at zero phase and at the nominal impedance. And, they're coupled = they merely transfer power along the TML, at the "speed of light" times contraction ratio. Two catches here: each frequency results in different parameters of the lump/atom - so you cannot sweep the f while keeping the LC parameters. And: how do you calculate the f(res) of the series?